# Why isn't `INSERT ROW` working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL piece of code that every time a user inserts a name creates a new column with the name (and this part works fine). I also want it to add a row to that column with the respective comment given by the user. I don't see why this add row statement won't work.

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);

$add = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE Names ADD $value Text NOT NULL");

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Names VALUES $comment");
```

Comment: Constantly changing data structure is not consdered good practice! Why do you need to add a new field to names table every time?

Comment: Why are user's getting their own columns?

Comment: @chris85 I thought a question like this would come around. I want it so that every user can insert a name, and then eventually fill a large number of comments which will fill the rows of that name. I just thought it would work that way. All the names in the columns, all the rows in the rows.

Comment: Having read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html and checking for errors on your query http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php  would have avoided this question (a debugging one at that) altogether.

Comment: I think you'll find issues with this approach. I'd maybe make 2 tables; users and comments. In comments have a userid that relates to the user's id in users table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Names (`$value`) VALUES ('$comment')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You need to specify the column list.

Ideally you should start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or an ORM to be able to work and debug easier

Comment: Actually, that worked now, thank you!

Comment: @Nockingam at least provide a meaningful feedback with exact error message!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['comment']);

$add = mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE Names ADD '{$value}' Text NOT NULL");

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO Names({$value}) VALUES('{$comment}')");
```

Comment: Why should anyone "*try this*"? A good answer should at least  include what you changed and why you changed those things.